# Spring XD: Writing an aggregator; how to output asynchronously, or at least not 1:1?

Tags: aggregation, spring-xd

Per the title, are there best practices, examples, etc. for writing an aggregator transformer module?  We have a situation in which our aggregation is based on a timestamp in the data, and the data may come out of order, late, or even TOO late to consider.

For the "too late" case, we plan on using a `filter` to remove them before the transformer sees them.

However, this gets down to the basic question - how does one write a transformer to aggregate when the output of the aggregator is not based on the input?  Can one be written to output to the same XD stream asynchronously?  Or even, can one write a transformer to output based on some aspect of the input, but only on certain inputs and not output anything on the others?

As a concrete, albeit contrived, example, I want an aggregator to take a Tuple of (String, Int), and sum the Int's based on the String, and then ONLY output the aggregations when the String is a certain value; say "stop".  Easy enough to demonstrate:

```
(foo, 1)
(bar, 2)
(foo, 2)
(stop, 0)
```

When the last tuple enters the transformer, I should emit a stream of tuples:

```
(foo, 3)
(bar, 2)
```

How is a transformer written to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `aggregator` processor module, not a `transform`. The [standard aggregator module](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#aggregator) doesn't have it, but the [Spring Integration aggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) can discard late messages via a `discard-channel` (if `expire-groups-on-completion` is `false`).

The aggregator itself, when the release strategy determines that a group can be released (or via  `group-timeout`), can do anything you want with the group, returning any kind of result that is emitted and will go to the next module in the stream. So you would typically do your tuple accumulation there, or use the default aggregator, which will release a collection and you can use a `transform` module downstream.

The aggregator is a passive component by default; unless you configure a `MessageGroupStoreReaper` or use `group-timeout`, group release is only triggered when a message arrives for that group (has the same correlation).

Comment: Thanks Gary.  One thing that I'm having a lot of trouble with on XD is the assumption that the user will ONLY be using it to string together existing stuff and not writing one's own.  If I want to write my own aggregator, what method must I implement (akin to "transform()")?  What is the signature?  Is this documented anywhere?  Am I supposed to be looking in Integration instead of XD docs for this sort of thing?

Comment: There's no such assumption; there's a [section in the guide that talks about Developing Modules and Extensions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/#developing-modules-and-extensions). Yes, XD modules are Spring Integration flows so the details are in the [Spring Integration Reference Document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/). XD 1.1 will support creating modules with the [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) instead of using XML configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that section 100 times, and the only code I can find there that shows method names or signatures are tests, or for the transform method.  What does one implement for a `filter`, for example.  Am I looking in the wrong spot(s)?

Comment: See the Spring Integration documentation - a filter can reference a POJO method that returns a boolean, passing in the payload, or the entire message, or you can use a SpEL expression `<filter ... expression="payload.foo == 'bar'" />` will filter out all messages where the payload (a javabean in this case) has its `foo` property not set to `bar`. XD is built on top of Spring Integration so there is some expectation of Spring Integration knowledge when customizing.

Comment: I think I identify with what Michael is facing. It isn't actually in the technical details as it is about the process of building something on XD. How do "I/we" know if our solution is really the nicest way of doing things. In my area of application I can think of at least 3 equally good ways of solving the exact same problem. A helpful set of "do's and don'ts" could potentially save a whole lot development time for better solutions. I'm not even sure if this a stackoverflow kind of answer, but it's coming from a heavy user, and not necessarily the most experienced programmer.